# Magento 2 - Custom Page Layout

Tags: magento2, module, layout, template

I wish to add a custom home page layout in Magento 2.

[image: Dropdown]

In Magento 1, it's very simple, i create my module :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Custom>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Vendor_Custom>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and i create a config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <custom_home_page>
                    <label>Custom Home Page</label>
                    <template>page/home.phtml</template>
                </custom_home_page>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

It's possible to do something similar in Magento 2?

Comment: See also the topic on [creating a theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) in the Frontend Developers Guide.

Answer (score 13):

Create layouts.xml following location:

```
[namespace]/[modulename]/view/frontend/layouts.xml
```

Content should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="homepage">
        <label translate="true">Custom Homepage</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Create your new custom page layout **(ex: homepage.xml)** following location:

```
[namespace]/[modulename]/view/frontend/page_layout/homepage.xml
```

Content should be well structure page layout. So in your case copy of existing page layout into your custom page layout. All page layouts locate:

```
magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/*
```

Answer (score 7):

Use 1st answer for page layout updates, but change locations:

For `layouts.xml` move it to

```
app/design/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme_name]/Magento_Theme/
```

and

For `homepage.xml` move it to

```
app/design/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme_name]/Magento_Theme/page_layout/
```

I've tried 1st answer example but it didn't work.