# How to display some module (<block>) at a particular page (main)

Tags: magento2, module, layout, magento-2.1

**Problem**

There is properly working custom module (as far as I'm concerned), that outputs map. I need to display it **only at main page** at the `content` container.

Now it outputs at **every page** `content` container.

---

**What was done**

First of all, I supposed, that it is doing by changing extended layout in the theme.

1. At:

`/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

was written:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="<Vendor>\Map\Block\Map" name="map" template="<Vendor>_Map::map.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I saw, that I can control displaying by changing the name, so i tried to use quite a lot of options, that PhpStorm gave me (especially with `*.main.*`).

2. The second option was to create custom `container` and `move` it, but in process I realised, that I can't select `destination` at the particular page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in incomplete understanding of Magento2 layout system.

Found an answer at:

[Magento 2 - Custom Page Layout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95729/magento-2-custom-page-layout)